# Configuring IntelliJ to Use Groovy Compiler Instead of Java Compiler

Tags: java, maven, groovy, intellij-idea

In my maven project, I'm currently mixing my Java code with some Groovy code. I'm using Groovy mostly to construct the beans at this point. Some of my Java code uses the Groovy beans directly.

I configured the Maven Compiler Plugin like this:-

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0-01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5-03</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

When I run my testcases using `mvn test`, it works just fine.

However, when I run the testcases directly from IntelliJ by right clicking the test file and run it, I'm getting "cannot find symbol" errors on the Groovy beans. When I read the error log, IntelliJ uses Java compiler to compile my project before running the test... thus, the tests fail.

I can't seem to figure out how to instruct IntelliJ to always use the Groovy compiler instead of Java compiler.

What should I change under SDK so that Groovy compiler will be used? I tried adding Groovy related JAR files, but I got other errors.

[image]

**UPDATE 1: Per @Seagull suggestion**

I added groovy JARs under "Global Libraries":-

[image]

When I executed the test file directly from IntelliJ, I'm getting some Groovy warnings and I still get the same error:-

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have an Groovy Framework Support for your project? Try to add it, by right-clicking on project root folder in Project view, and select an existing, or create a new Groovy sdk. Also it will add Groovy library in module dependency.

Comment: There's no option for me to do so. I went to "Project SDK" under "Project" Settings, when I add new "JDK" and point it to my downloaded Groovy SDK, it doesn't detect anything.

Comment: Groovy has no separated SDK, to be listed there. Try to create an ordinary 'Global library', it's icon will change to Groovy icon. Add it to your module, and it may work.

Comment: Under 'Global Libraries', there's only these options: Java, JavaScript, From Maven and ActionScript/Flex. I tried Java and point to Groovy and that didn't work. I also tried Maven pointing to groovy-all, and I still get the same 'cannot find symbol' error.

Comment: Groovy-all is for embedding, it didn't point Intellij idea, that this is a groovy framework. In Global Libraryes select java, point to $GROOVY_HOME/lib/ . It should look like [screenshot](https://www.monosnap.com/image/FBndpbJ4Y8Ry2ZJGfTZKTqQsW)

Comment: @Seagull, I updated my post... it didn't work for me.

Comment: Strange. Sorry, that i can't help you. It's look like groovyc is running, because of it warning output. At this moment I have no idea whats going on. If it's a groovy bean, used from java I suggest you to check idea-generated stubs, located on my macbook at $USER_HOME/Library/Caches/IdeaIC13/compile-server/..._81ea93a7/groovyStubs/groovy/java-production/SomeClass.java

It may be bug with idea stub compiler. Like discussed here [JetBrains_DevNet](/Users/seagull/Library/Caches/IdeaIC13/compile-server/nlps_81ea93a7/groovyStubs/groovy/java-production/uima/A.java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the reply from the IntelliJ support team on January 2, 2014 regarding this problem:-

> IDEA uses groovyc to generate Java stubs for Groovy classes to allow
>   for seamless interop. Unfortunately stub generation code doesn't
>   launch AST transformations (e.g. Immutable) and so the methods
>   generated by those transformations don't make it into Java stubs,
>   hence Java compiler doesn't see them.
>
> Unfortunately I see no workarounds that don't require modifying your
>   project. One would be to place Groovy files into a separate module.
>   Another would be to change the call places into Groovy. The third one
>   would be to replace @Immutable with @Canonical and generate the
>   constructor so that it's actually in the code (and the stubs will
>   contain it).
>
> You may also vote/watch http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-52379
>   to support Eclipse Groovy compiler.

I ended up removing both `@Immutable` and `@Canonical` and create my own constructors, for 2 reasons:-

- It allows me to run my test case directly from IntelliJ.
- It cleans up JaCoCo code coverage report significantly caused by the unused constructors provided for free by `@Immutable` and `@Canonical`.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem on the latest version of Intellij *ideaIC-15.0.3-custom-jdk-bundled.dmg* on MAC *10.10.5*, JDK *1.8.0_60*.

Including all steps for posterity...

1. From the terminal, I installed the latest version of `groovy`, using [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/): `sdk install groovy 2.4.5`
2. In Intellij, right-click on top project > select "Add Framework Support..." > Add `groovy 2.4.5` (if it hasn't already been added).
3. In Intellij, "Preferences" > "Build, Execution, Deployment" > "Compiler" > "Resource patterns:" > change the order from `!?*.java;!?*.groovy` to `!?*.groovy;!?*.java`
4. Recompile the project (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>), it should now compile successfully.